# Adding two methods with assignment operator

Tags: java, opengl

I have been playing about with inheritance and abstract classes. I'm wondering why I cant add these two methods together in the update method, as they both return a value.

```
package com.dashed.game;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import com.dashed.game.entity.MoveableEntity;

public class Box extends MoveableEntity {

public Box(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
    super(x, y, width, height);
    setDx(0.5);
}

public void update(){
    getX() += getDx();
}

public void draw(){
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2d(getX(), getY());
        glVertex2d(getX() + getWidth(), getY());
        glVertex2d(getX() + getWidth(), getY() + getHeight());
        glVertex2d(getX(), getY() + getHeight());
    glEnd();
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign a value to a value.  Presumably the `getX()` method returns a value instead of `void`.  A value can only be assigned to a variable, such as:

```
int x = getX();
x += getDx();
setX(x);  // May need to do something like this too.
```

Answer (score 0):

`getX()` is a readonly method, used to only return its value. if you want to set it, there should be a setter for it and then you can update its value like:

```
setX((getX() + getDx()));
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `getX() += getDx();`? getX() is just an integer *value*, which doesn't denote some *variable*.

Maybe you should you some method to assign `x`:

```
setX(getX() + getDx());
```

You may just google for something like `lvalue`/`rvalue` to  understand what you can use in the right part of the assignment statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
getX() += getDx();
```

Is equivalent to:

```
getX() = getX() + getDx();
```

You cannot add things to a method. You need a numeric variable (lvar) on the left side of an assignment expression.